# How to make legacy extension work in tfs 2017?

Tags: javascript, tfs

Related to this [How to make legacy extension (tfs2013) work in tfs2015 update 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326940/how-to-make-legacy-extension-tfs2013-work-in-tfs2015-update-2) Main purpose - hide panel in backlogs

I have TFS 2017 on-premise installation and 4 files:

- manifest.xml
- HideAddPanel.js
- HideAddPanel.debug.js
- HideAddPanel.min.js

manifest.xml

```
<WebAccess version="15.0">
  <plugin moreinfo="http://mypage.com" name="Hide Add Panel" vendor="myvendor" version="1.0">
   <modules>
     <module loadAfter="TFS.Agile.TaskBoard" namespace="HideAddPanel.js"></module>
     <module loadAfter="TFS.Agile.Boards.Controls" namespace="HideAddPanel.js"></module>
   </modules>
  </plugin>
</WebAccess>
```

HideAddPanel.js

```
TFS.module("HideAddPanel", 
[ "VSS\\Utils\\Core",
        "VSS\\Utils\\UI"],
    function () { 
   $(".panel-region").hide();
});
```

Then I zip this four files and install it, enable extension on tfs2017, but nothing happens on backlogs - in features, stories, iteration backlogs quick add panel is present. And I don't understand from where this "TFS.Agile.XXX" are taken and how to find them.

Need help

Comment: When you do the install did you get any error info ? Did you got some related info in the Event view on TFS server?  Try to create a new project to check if it works.

Comment: No, when plugin is installin there is no error. I see nothing special in event viewer after install and enablement plugin.

Comment: Hello, @Vertigo How did you fix this issue at last? I got the same problem with you...

Comment: I solved problem with changing original javascript files in TFS