# how to hide extension point of visual studio team foundation server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-devops-extensions

These buttons are added as extension points by me, now i would like to hide these buttons when 
"recycle bin" query runs as vsts "link to work item" button hide. please see attachments.

How to hide

[image: How to hide]

Sample code

[image: Sample code]

Answer (score 1):

The work-item-query bar in *assigned to me* and *recycle bin*  is using the same target: `ms.vss-work-web.work-item-query-results-toolbar-menu`

If you use this target for your extension, the button will list for both *assigned to me* and *recycle bin*.

The `open/link to work item` system button is also just using some code hidden themselves when loading the query toolbar in recycle bin. Which is more related to UI.  However the code is not open, it's not able to achieve this for extension. About the UI related for the extension, you could also take a look at the answer in this question: [How to hide quick add panel Backlogs Items using VSTS extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323608/how-to-hide-quick-add-panel-backlogs-items-using-vsts-extension)

You could add a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) here suggest either separate targets in *assigned to me* and *recycle bin* for the query tool bar, or provide a way to hidden button in extension json.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have to go with your suggestion, I have added a uservoice. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/30966130-provide-a-way-to-hide-extension-point-work-item